# Error module Datawig 0.1.12 in Python 3.7.7: OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python

I installed the latest (0.1.12) version of Datawig module. I've considered all the package requirements:

- scikit-learn[alldeps]==0.22.1
- typing==3.6.6
- pandas==0.25.3
- mxnet==1.4.0

But when I run the script,

```
    import datawig
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/python_ummd/venv/Lib/imputation.py", line 7, in
import datawig
File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\untitled1\venv\bin\lib\site-packages\datawig_init_.py", line 2, in
from .column_encoders import CategoricalEncoder, BowEncoder, NumericalEncoder, SequentialEncoder
File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\untitled1\venv\bin\lib\site-packages\datawig\column_encoders.py", line 26, in
import mxnet as mx
File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\untitled1\venv\bin\lib\site-packages\mxnet_init_.py", line 24, in
from .context import Context, current_context, cpu, gpu, cpu_pinned
File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\untitled1\venv\bin\lib\site-packages\mxnet\context.py", line 24, in
from .base import classproperty, with_metaclass, _MXClassPropertyMetaClass
File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\untitled1\venv\bin\lib\site-packages\mxnet\base.py", line 213, in
_LIB = _load_lib()
File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\untitled1\venv\bin\lib\site-packages\mxnet\base.py", line 204, in load_lib
lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path[0], ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL)
File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes_init.py", line 364, in init
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I want to use SimpleImputer. I use Windows [Version 10.0.18363.836], Python 3.7.7, Pycharm 2020.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a windows machine at my hands, so can't confirm but maybe using the same python bit-width as your dll will help, see here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/1740

You can try a Python version different from the one where you encountered the error (32bit or 64bit).

Comment: Hi Tammo, thank you again for your reply. I deinstalled everything and downloaded Pycharm again. I installed python 3.7 and also installed all the modules again. Everything must be 64bit now. But I am getting still the same error only for Datawig but not for other modules. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, version 1.4.0